# Zurb Foundation Block Grid causing horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Just reported this as a possible issue on github, but maybe I'm just doing something wrong!

Check out the fiddle to see this happening: http://jsfiddle.net/bu2Dw/1/

If you reduce the width of the window below the large page size, the negative margin that the default foundation css applies to the  element causes the horizontal scrollbar to appear.

Just drop the following code into any foundation page and resize the window to see this happen. "Contain to grid" on the block grid div stops the scrollbar but it messes up the margins.

```
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Using both block grids together for different layouts -->
        <ul class="small-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-5">
          <li><img src="http://placehold.it/395x590" alt="image1" /></li>
          <li><img src="http://placehold.it/395x590" alt="image2" /></li>
          <li><img src="http://placehold.it/395x590" alt="image3" /></li>
          <li><img src="http://placehold.it/395x590" alt="image4" /></li>
          <li><img src="http://placehold.it/395x590" alt="image5" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should wrap the block-grid container in a columns div e.g. `<div class="twelve columns">`; putting it directly in a `<div class="row">` is not enough.

See your fiddle with this correction: http://jsfiddle.net/guybrushthreepwood/z5xj8/1/

Comment: Thanks for that.  I tried that too.  The problem still happens if you set the column spacing to be zero. I have a design where the columns need to be next to each other with no spacing. Because of this the negative margin on the block grid causes the horizontal scrollbar regardless of how it's wrapped.

Comment: @CarlEdwards Can't you use a margin:0 !important; and override the negative margin?

Comment: Well, no, not really. Setting the <ul> to 0 margin would put the edges in the right place but then the far left and far right <li> would be inset by half the block-grid spacing. So default is 20px, each <li> element has left & right padding of half that, so 10px (0.625em).